# Pop screen in GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have a list screen like below
[image]
I would like click back in screen 5 and pop to screen 2 ,
When click back screen 2 -> pop to screen 1
Can you help me check it. Thanks

I use GetX.
and push screen 1 -> 5

```
Future<dynamic> goToScreen(Widget screen,
    {dynamic arguments, bool preventDuplicates = true}) async {
  int? id = Get.find<MainController>().currentScreenModel.navKey;
  if (arguments != null) {
    DataHolder().args = arguments;
  }
  return Get.to(() => screen,
      id: id, arguments: arguments, preventDuplicates: preventDuplicates);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the times you want to go back are fixed, in your case, 3 times, you can just use `Get.close(3)`, this will pop the screen 3 times.

But, if you're not sure if in the future this could change, you can also use the route name (which is harder to get since you're using unnamed routes) `Get.until((route) => Get.currentRoute == yourRouteName);`.

When you use `Get.to`, GetX is going to print your route name in the console, you can copy the screen 2 route's name and then use that with `Get.until`.